# Azure Queue Storage Message Size

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, azure-storage

From this [Windows Azure MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/76d69b20-265c-4c53-9eee-dbdf066e5762), I understand that the queue message size
should be 8KB. We can calculate the message size by 6144 byte * 4/3 (base64 encoding).

We are storing message as XML messages (string).

How to calculate the byte size from string in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The byte size of a string is dependant on your encoding. This is how you get it for the UTF8 encoding, as example.

```
var byteSize = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml).GetLength(0);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jappjan, the bytSize returned is in KB?

Comment: You can also use System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("")